# Malfunctioning LED bulb flickers when switch turned off

Tags: lighting, switch, light-fixture, light-bulb

I have a bathroom light fixture that has three LED bulbs in it. One of the bulbs died the other day, and I haven't gotten around to replacing it yet. When the light switch is on, two of the bulbs light up and the third does not, exactly as I would expect from a fixture with one malfunctioning bulb.

I just noticed an odd thing, however, that when I turn light switch off, the two good bulbs turn off as normal, but the dead bulb (sometimes) flickers and lights up momentarily about a second *after* the switch is turned to the off position. I was surprised this was even possible, as I expected the light switch should immediately prevent any current from going through the bulb. What's happening here - how can the bulb light up when the switch is off? Is this indicative of any kind of wiring problem, or just that the LED bulb needs replacement?

Comment: there is a stored charge inside the light bulb power supply

Comment: LED bulbs don't burn out.  They malfunction. Now, is there a dimmer or other sophisticated switch on this circuit?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Interesting, I always just used the term "burned out" for any dead bulb and never considered that it wouldn't apply to LEDs. There's no dimmer, just a simple switch.

Comment: Yes, LEDs work very differently.  You have an essentially indestructible light emitter (it is a solid state semiconductor after all), fed DC power from an electronic power supply which is "low bidder" and has problems like cheap components failing (e.g. capacitors), RoHS solder crystallizing, etc.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the wiring at the switch box in particular?

Comment: That's induction between wires: add a 100uF condenser parallel to the light to discharde inducted currents. Second option is to use two-pole switch breaking both phase and neutral